# VS2010 Code: 2104 Could not download the Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I've just started getting this Javascript error running VS2010 with SL4

```
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings
```

Everything was working fine, changed 1 line of code to use a RegularExpression in the web project (using the Silverlight Business Application template) then when rebuilding I get this error.

Google says this is IIS and mimetype related. I'm using Cassini not IIS with VS2010.

Rebooted, cleared xap from IE cache. Error on both IE and FF.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using the RC or Beta?

Comment: I'm getting same error 5of7 MB xap downloading but not anymore. Sometimes 2of7? Any of solution below is a cure for me.

Answer (score 8):

I just got this error myself.  Looking at source control and my project I noticed that the original test pages that were created when I setup the project got replaced by two new test pages (one .aspx and one .html).

I removed the newly created pages and went back to the old test pages and things started working.

If your situation isn't the same as mine, then just check your silverlightControlHost div in your test page and make sure you are pointing to the correct .xap file and runtime.

Comment: wow.. I made the mistake of "/" instead of "\" for path to define the value of the xap source location.  If yer not using the default "ClientBin" then you might fall into this trap too (who knew!?)

Answer (score 3):

if youre not running in IIS then just check your silverlightControlHost div in your test page and make sure you are pointing to the correct .xap file and runtime.

If you were in MVC you could do something similar...

```
<param name="source" value="@Url.Content("~/ClientBin/NameOfYourSlAppGoesHere.xap")" />
```

Comment: Would you need to enclose the Url.Content in <% %>? So something like value="<%= Url.Content("~/ClientBin/...") %>"

Answer (score 3):

Follow the Step :

> On Hosting project, Properties > Silverlight Applications > Add..

This solved my Problem.
Simple error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with my provider. When I looked at the MIME type everything seemed to be OK:

> .xap => application/x-silverlight-app

which seems to be the default value on IIS 6. Then I looked at the webpage VS 2010 created and noticed that it has a MIME type of

> **application/x-silverlight-2**

I changed the MIME type on IIS according to the webpage's type and - my silverlight application gets loaded without any error!

Comment: The same solution helped me. The strange thing is, though, that changing it back did not reintroduce the problem. In other words, it seems to be a temporary problem (and only for a specific Silverlight control).

Answer (score 1):

This error often occurs because the MIME type is not set, as you have found for yourself.  It can also be a mask for the HTTP error.  You can see the message by pulling up the XAP file directly from your browser (http://yourwebsite/ClientBin/filename.xap).  The file will either attempt to download, or it will show you an HTTP Error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and the file does attempt to download.  What's the next step?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue on VS 2010. And the reason was that the .**xap file was not getting copied to ClientBin directory** of the hosting web site project.

Reason was the association from the hosting web site project to the silverlight project was missing for some reason. (should be due to some restructuring of the projects that I've done recently in my case)
I had to re-add the association from the hosting web site project to the silverlight project.

Steps:
On Hosting project, Properties > Silverlight Applications > Add..

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and it was solved with the help of this blog post: http://vanderbiest.org/blog/2009/10/27/2104-silverlight-initialization-error/

Just ensuring that IIS_IUSRS has read and read & execute permission on the XAP file might fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> .xap file was not getting copied to ClientBin directory

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that http://mysite/ClientBin/MyApp.xap was returning a 404. The build process was copying the XAP file into /ClientBin/DEBUG/ - I expect this is because someone told it to copy the XAP file to a config specific folder. To fix it I did the following...

1. Go to the properties of your website.
2. Go to the Silverlight Apps page.
3. If your Silverlight app is already referenced there, remove it.
4. Now click Add.
5. Select your existing SL app.
6. Make sure "Copy to a config specific folder" is **NOT** checked!

Answer (score 0):

for my case it occured In IE and in chrom the project work.
it resolved by
 disable protected mode in IE.(Internet Option -->Security)

Answer (score 0):

For my case (with visual studio 2012), one of the projects in the solution wasn't loaded...

right click->reload project.

fixed.